# Chart js is not working on angular 7 project

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the Chart.js in my Angular 7 project. I installed the chart.js and ng2-chart into my application. Please see my code below:

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
            ],
```

**app.module**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
imports: [
 ...
 ChartsModule
]
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usage-cpu',
  templateUrl: './usage-cpu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usage-cpu.component.css']
})
export class UsageCpuComponent implements OnInit {

  public pieChartLabels:string[] = ["Pending", "InProgress", "OnHold", "Complete", "Cancelled"];
  public pieChartData:number[] = [21, 39, 10, 14, 16];
  public pieChartType:string = 'pie';
  public pieChartOptions:any = {'backgroundColor': [
               "#FF6384",
            "#4BC0C0",
            "#FFCE56",
            "#E7E9ED",
            "#36A2EB"
            ]}

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

    // events on slice click
    public chartClicked(e:any):void {
      console.log(e);
    }

   // event on pie chart slice hover
    public chartHovered(e:any):void {
      console.log(e);
    }

}
```

**html**

```
<h2 class="text-center">PIE chart using Chartjs and Angular</h2>
<canvas
  baseChart
  [data]="pieChartData"
  [labels]="pieChartLabels"
  [chartType]="pieChartType"
  [options]="pieChartOptions"
  (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
  (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
>
</canvas>
```

Using all of this code, I get this error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>     at ng2-charts.js:230
>     at Module../node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm5/ng2-charts.js (ng2-charts.js:232)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
>     at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
>     at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
>     at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
>     at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
```

[image]

Can you please show me how to do this right. Thank you.

Comment: check for support at the GitHub or npm!

Answer (score 0):

Delete this in angular.json:

```
   "./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics on angular 7, but in 8 I was able to set it up with some imports.
Once you installed it from npm you need to do some imports so as to integrate it. You can find it in the migration section in the chartjs documantation page, something like this:

> Chart.js 3 is tree-shakeable. So if you are using it as an npm module in a project and want to make use of this feature, you need to import and register the controllers, elements, scales and plugins you want to use, for a list of all the available items to import see integration. You will not have to call register if importing Chart.js via a script tag or from the auto register path as an npm module, in this case you will not get the tree shaking benefits.

The import that worked for me was this:

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);
```